# The field of quotients of integral domain and two related questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $D$ be integral domain. We know that we are able to construct the field of quotients $F$. More exactly the field $F$ consists of all equivalence classes $[a,b]$, where $a\in D$, $b\in D-\{0\}$ and

$$[a,b]=\{(c,d)\in D\times D-\{0\}: (a,b)\sim(c,d)\},$$

where we claim that $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ iff $ad=bc$.

It is obvious that $D$ **is not the subset of** $F$, so we cannot say that $D\subset F$.

The correct statement is the following: $D \hookrightarrow F$ i.e. there exists $\phi: D\to F$ such that $\phi$ - injective homomorphism.

Let's move on to the questions.

**1)** We know that $\mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots\}$ the set of integers and $\mathbb{Q}$ the set of rational numbers.

However $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of all equivalence classes $[a,b]$, where we can denote $[a,b]$ by symbol $\frac{a}{b}$. The set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{Q}$ through mapping $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$ defined by $\phi(n)=[n,1]=\frac{n}{1}$.

We cannot say that $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}$ because their elements have distinct nature. But why many authors write that $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}$?

**2)** My second question also deals with this topic so I've decided not to create new one.

Let $R$ be Euclidean ring. We know that in Euclidean ring $R$ *greatest common divisor* and *least common multiple* always exist! And my book states that $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ and $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ have the following relation: $$\text{lcm}(a,b)=\dfrac{ab}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}.$$

I have big misunderstanding with this question. The LHS of this identity is the $\text{lcm}(a,b)$ which is an element of Euclidean ring $R$ but the RHS of identity is the fraction $\frac{ab}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}$ which is an equivalence class and it is the element of quotient field but not an element of Euclidean ring $R$. There is such a question: *How can we say that they are equal? if they even have different nature.*

I would be very very thankful for detailed explanation since I am trying to understand both question about 3 weeks but no results. Also I was trying to find some useful links here but it did not give results. So please help me!

Comment: The symbol $\subset$ means an injective map, too.

Comment: @janmarqz, I have never seen this kind of definition. Could you provide a link( or book)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: we *identify* $D$ (or $\mathbf Z$) with its canonical image in $F$ ($\mathbf Q$).

Recall that $\mathbf Z$ itself is constructed from $\mathbf N$  as the set of equivalence classes in $\mathbf N^2$ for the relation 
$$(a,b)\sim (c,d)\overset{\text{def}}{\iff} a+d=b+c,$$
so $\mathbf N$ isn't really a subset of $\mathbf Z$, yet we use the identification of  $\mathbf N$ with its canonical image in $\mathbf N^2/\sim$.

The answer to your second question follows from these considerations. Note that  $\;\dfrac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$ can be interpreted a the quotient of $ab$ by $\gcd(a,b)$, so it's an element of the Euclidean domain. And anyway the relation can be written entirely in $D$ as
$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\,\gcd(a,b)=ab.$$

Comment: Dear Bernard! Thanks a lot for reply. I have read your answer many times and that's what I've grasped from it:

1) We know that $\mathbb{Z}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{Q}$ i.e. $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$. In other words, there exists $\phi:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Q}$  by $\phi(n)=[n,1]=\frac{n}{1}$ where $\phi$ - injective homomorphism. We cannot say that $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}$ however if we identify $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\phi(\mathbb{Z})$ then everything will be fine (after this identification we have the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: In other words, we identify $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\frac{n}{1}\in \mathbb{Q}$. Right?

2) Considering your remark to my second question. Since $\text{gcd}(a,b)|a$ then $\text{gcd}(a,b)|ab$ so $\exists x\in R$ such that $ab=\text{gcd}(a,b)x$. Then $[ab, \text{gcd}(a,b)]=[x,1]$ or symbolically $\frac{ab}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}=\frac{x}{1}$ (these fractions are elements of the field of quotients $F$). Since we identify $\frac{x}{1}\in F$ with $x\in R$ then we can say that $\frac{ab}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}=x\in R$.

Comment: In other words, we can consider $\frac{ab}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}$ as the element of Euclidean domain $R$. 

But I have one question: We get that $\frac{ab}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}=x$ in $R$. What does this equality mean in $R$? Namely the symbol $\frac{ab}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}$? And how it follows that $ab=\text{gcd}(a,b)x$?

Would be very grateful for your reply!

Comment: In $R$, $\frac{ab}{\gcd(a,b)}$ is another notation for the quotient (in the sense of Euclidean division) of $ab $ by $\gcd(a,b)$. I believe it is sometimes denoted $ab\div\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Ok. If $ab/\text{gcd}(a,b)=x$ how it follows that $ab=\text{gcd}(a,b)x$?

Comment: It is equivalent if you start from the Euclidean division. From the point of view of the field of  fractions, one should write $ab/\gcd(a,b)=x/1\implies ab/1=(x\gcd(a,b))/1$, or using the reverse identification, $ab=x\,\gcd(a,b)$.